# bash get exitcode of su script execution

Tags: bash, sh

I have a shell script when need to run as a particular user. So I call that script as below,

```
su - testuser -c "/root/check_package.sh | tee -a /var/log/check_package.log"
```

So after this when I check the last execution exitcode it returns always `0` only even if that script fails.

I tried something below also which didn't help,

```
su - testuser -c "/root/check_package.sh | tee -a /var/log/check_package.log && echo $? || echo $?"
```

Is there way to get the exitcode of command whatever running through su.

Comment: The `tee` is your problem, not `su` (which is not `sudo`).

Comment: ...which is to say: `su` already does correctly pass exit status through. You can easily test this yourself: Run `su - testuser -c "exit 2"; echo $?`

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is not `su`, but `tee`: By default, the shell exits with the exit status of *the last pipeline component*; in your code, that component is not `check_package.sh`, but instead is `tee`.

If your `/bin/sh` is provided by bash (as opposed to `ash`, `dash`, or another POSIX-baseline shell), use `set -o pipefail` to cause the entirely pipeline to fail if any component of it does:

```
su - testuser -c "set -o pipefail; /root/check_package.sh | tee -a /var/log/check_package.log"
```

Alternately, you can do the `tee` out-of-band with redirection to a process substitution (though this requires your current user to have permission to write to `check_package.log`):

```
su - testuser -c "/root/check_package.sh" > >(tee -a /var/log/check_package.log
```

Answer (score 2):

Both `su` and `sudo` exit with the exit status of the command they execute (if authentication succeeded):

```
$ sudo false; echo $?
1
$ su -c false; echo $?
1
```

Your problem is that the command pipeline that `su` runs is a pipeline.  The exit status of your pipeline is that of the `tee` command (which succeeds), but what you really want is that of the first command in the pipeline.

If your shell is bash, you have a couple of options:

- `set -o pipefail` before your pipeline, which will make it return the rightmost failure value of all the commands if any of them fail
- Examine the specific member of the `PIPESTATUS` array variable - this can give you the exit status of the first command whether or not `tee` succeeds.

Examples:

```
$ sudo bash -c "false | tee -a /dev/null"; echo $?
0
$ sudo bash -c "set -o pipefail; false | tee -a /dev/null"; echo $?
1
$ sudo bash -c 'false | tee -a /dev/null; exit ${PIPESTATUS[0]}'; echo $?
1
```

You will get similar results using `su -c`, if your system shell (in `/bin/sh`) is Bash.  If not, then you'd need to explicitly invoke bash, at which point `sudo` is clearly simpler.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy and Tony. Thanks! Both of it worked charm!

Comment: Also I have some customized banner for that user and when I do su through shell script then that banner message also prints. I tried to hide that message using `su - testuser -s /usr/bin/id `. But some script I need to run along with arguments and If I run the same way by calling those scripts with argument in double/single quotes then its not working.

Comment: @Ravi, that sounds like a separate question (and may be more appropriate for [unix.se], as it's not actually a programming issue).  When asking it, you might want to refer to this question if it helps provide the context.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue today, in case the topic is still open here my solution, otherwise just ignore it...

I wrote a bash script (let's say my_script.sh) which looks more or less like this:

```
### FUNCTIONS ### 
<all functions listed in the main script which do what I want...>

### MAIN SCRIPT ### calls the functions defined in the section above
main_script() { 
  log_message "START" 0
  check_env
  check_data
  create_package
  tar_package
  zip_package
  log_message "END" 0
}

main_script |tee -a ${var_log} # executes script and writes info into log file
var_sta=${PIPESTATUS[0]} # captures status of pipeline
exit ${var_sta} # exits with value of status
```

It works when you call the script directly or in sudo mode